# Versioning in Configuration Management

Tags: version-control, configuration

If there are 55 versions of a file in any configuration management system and then a developer checked out the 50th version...edit it and then check in again...what will be the new version of the file ?

Will it be 56th ?
or a new version would be 51th...and existing versions will be incremented by one.

Comment: This depends on the version control system. In Git, it would be a second child of the 50th version. Its notion of commits has no inherent sequence to them.

Answer (score 2):

Surely not the 51th, changes are incremental in time, not in content.

To have a clear history of the changes, there will be be a 56th version for reverting changes that occured between the 51 and 55, in order to make it clear that he's going back. Then anothor version, the 57th for the changes he actually makes.

Answer (score 0):

Should be version 56, and file merge would happen when checking in the file if there is any conflick between v55 and the new version.

Another good way to manage the versions is to branch out the historic version (v50). After you modify the files (like adding features, fixing bugs, etc.), you can merge it back to the original.